# How to get column with max value for each key?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table :

```
CREATE TABLE ask (
    item TEXT ,
    value INTEGRER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ask (item,value) VALUES
("A", 1),
("A", 4),
("A", 3),
("B", 0),
("B", 1),
("C", 2),
("C", 4);
```

| item | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 4 |

I want two additional columns with max and min values per item:

| item | value | min_val | max_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| A | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| C | 4 | 2 | 4 |

How can I get that in SQLite? This doesn't work:

```
SELECT *, max(value) AS max_val, min(val) AS min_val FROM ask;
```

Comment: "I want to add two additional columns" To what? To the existing table? Or do you want to create a new table which has those additional columns? Or do you just want to create a query which has a result/output as shown? Do you want to do the adding once? Do you want to make sure that those additional columns are updated when you add more values to the original table? Especially if the new values are relevant for e.g. the max? What should happen if you change existing entries relevantly?

Comment: I just want to create a query which has a result/output as shown

Comment: In which way did it fail? (I ask among other reasons, because being able to describe is step one of being able to solve....)

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions instead of aggregate functions:

```
SELECT *, 
       MIN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY item) min_val, 
       MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY item) max_val 
FROM ask;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d917daa67c0bc86ee06f57ffbf33fd7f).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table with the max/mins and then join it to create the desired table/result.

I.e.

```sql
select item, max(value) maxval, min(value) minval
from ask group by item;
```

then

```sql
SELECT a.item, a.value, maxval, minval
from 
  ask a
join
  (select item, max(value) maxval, min(value) minval from ask group by item) b
on a.item = b.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this. Most likely, you should keep your table as is and create a view instead:

```sql
CREATE VIEW ask_minmax AS (
    SELECT item,
           max(value) AS maxval,
           min(value) AS minval
    FROM ask
    GROUP BY item
);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of change text datatype to varchar in create table

```
CREATE TABLE ask (
item VARCHAR,
value Integer NOT NULL)
```

Insert Your Data

```
INSERT INTO ask (item,value)
VALUES
('A',   1),
('A',   4),
('A',   3),
('B',   0),
('B',   1),
('C',   2),
('C', 4);
```

Then after run my following query

```
With T1 As
(SELECT  item,max(value) as max_val, min(value) as min_val FROM ask
GROUP bY item)
Select T2.item,T2.value,T1.min_val,T1.max_val From ask T2
join T1 On T1.item = T2.item
```

Comment: when you used text as data type we can not used group by clause so change i change data type as varchar

Comment: `VARCHAR` is an alias for `TEXT` (there is [no `VARCHAR` data type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples)) which works perfectly fine on `GROUP BY`.